# Can I connect from my Android phone to a wearable watch which connects to my PC?

Tags: android, bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am want to send a file from my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5) to my wearable Samsung Galaxy which would then send it to my PC (all at once). All this is done via Bluetooth of course. The purpose of doing this is just for learning purposes and gaining knowledge on android programming. In other words, I want to transfer data over multiple devices using Bluetooth at the same time.

I would like to know if this is possible because this is a project that really interests me but I don't want to waste time if it can't be done. Let me know if further explanation is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking at the [Samsung Accessory SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#accessory).  This defines the communication link between the phone and the watch.  The underlying protocol is BlueTooth with help from libraries that ship with the Samsung Gear Manager app, available from the Samsung Galaxy Apps store.

There is no way *currently* to communicate directly from the PC to the watch--the phone will have to be the intermediary.

PC <---> Samsung phone/tablet <----> Gear watch

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it possible to connect from a phone/tablet to two gear watches and communicate with both all at once?

Comment: That is not possible currently. You can be connected to both, but only one connection is active at the same time. The other will not receive notifications and can't send data.